# Linking LLVM libraries on Windows with CMake and MinGW

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I've been writing a compiler using LLVM as the backend.  The CMake files I've written so far have worked on Linux, but I haven't had any luck on Windows.  The project is split into a library and "driver" executable with their own CMakeLists.txt in separate subdirectories.
The top level CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7.0)
project (compiler)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set (CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package (LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
message (STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message (STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")

include_directories (${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

add_subdirectory (Compiler_Lib)
add_subdirectory (Compiler_exe)
```

The CMakeLists.txt for the library:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7.0)

add_library (compiler_lib 
        AST.cpp
        AST.h
        parser.cpp
        parser.h
        scanner.cpp
        scanner.h
        token.cpp
        token.h
        visualizer.cpp
        visualizer.h
        codegen.cpp
        codegen.h)

target_include_directories (compiler_lib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(compiler_lib LLVM)
```

And the CMakeLists.txt for the executable (which is where linking to the libraries fails):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7.0)
project (compiler_exe)

add_executable (compiler_exe Compiler_exe.cpp getopt.h getopt.cpp)
target_link_libraries (compiler_exe LINK_PUBLIC LLVM compiler_lib)
```

I run the command `"c:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" .. -G"MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Users\James\llvm+clang-7.0.0-win64-msvc-release` where `C:\Users\James\llvm+clang-7.0.0-win64-msvc-release` is the path to prebuilt LLVM libraries.  However, running `mingw32-make` afterwards fails with the output

```
Scanning dependencies of target compiler_lib
[ 10%] Building CXX object Compiler_Lib/CMakeFiles/compiler_lib.dir/AST.cpp.obj
[ 20%] Building CXX object Compiler_Lib/CMakeFiles/compiler_lib.dir/parser.cpp.obj
[ 30%] Building CXX object Compiler_Lib/CMakeFiles/compiler_lib.dir/scanner.cpp.obj
[ 40%] Building CXX object Compiler_Lib/CMakeFiles/compiler_lib.dir/token.cpp.obj
[ 50%] Building CXX object Compiler_Lib/CMakeFiles/compiler_lib.dir/visualizer.cpp.obj
[ 60%] Building CXX object Compiler_Lib/CMakeFiles/compiler_lib.dir/codegen.cpp.obj
[ 70%] Linking CXX static library libcompiler_lib.a
[ 70%] Built target compiler_lib
Scanning dependencies of target compiler_exe
[ 80%] Building CXX object Compiler_exe/CMakeFiles/compiler_exe.dir/Compiler_exe.cpp.obj
[ 90%] Building CXX object Compiler_exe/CMakeFiles/compiler_exe.dir/getopt.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable compiler_exe.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLVM
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Compiler_exe\CMakeFiles\compiler_exe.dir\build.make:102: recipe for target 'Compiler_exe/compiler_exe.exe' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [Compiler_exe/compiler_exe.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:176: recipe for target 'Compiler_exe/CMakeFiles/compiler_exe.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Compiler_exe/CMakeFiles/compiler_exe.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is the first time I've used CMake so I could have missed something obvious, but as I say it seems to work on Linux.

Comment: The library name `LLVM` seems to be Linux-*specific*. You may collect llvm libraries using `llvm_map_components_to_libnames` function, or use `llvm_add_library` instead of `add_library`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, I have tried using `llvm_map_components_to_libnames` but run into issues with the LTO library.  I get the message `mingw32-make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'LTO-NOTFOUND', needed by 'Compiler_exe/compiler_exe.exe'.  Stop.`  This might be to do with the fact that the LTO library is shared but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

For the linking to succeed two things need to be true:

1) the file libLLVM.a needs to exist
2) that file has to be in a directory in the library search path

There should be a way to get cmake to tell you the list of places it searches for libraries, and you need to find a way to get wherever libLLVM.a exists into that list of dirs.

Apologies for the partial answer, but that's the troubleshooting path...